# Оператор ":" в конструкции for: помогите понять код

Tags: java, массивы

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] l = new int[10];
for (int i = 9; i > -1; i--) l[i] = s.nextInt();
for (int n : l) System.out.println(n);
```

задача была создать и перевернуть массив. Нашел решение на стороннем ресурсе, но не могу понять суть. Что значит (n : l) в 4 строчке?

Comment: Это foreach - обход всех элементов массива

Comment: Будет проще понять, если откажетесь от черезмерных сокращений - `for (int oneOf : arrayOfInt)`. Это в чатах можно вместо "Целую дорогая" -  "чмоки" писать, в коде не желательно.

Answer (score 4):

Это цикл `for` в стиле `foreach`.

Конструкция:

```
for (int n : l) {
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

аналогична следующей:

```
for (int i=0; i<l.length; i++) {
    int n = l[i];
    System.out.println(n);
}
```